# Where can I find Taizé groups in Prague?

Tags: religion, czech-republic, prague

I'm going to Prague for 5 days. 
Where I live use to go to the Taize' prayer in my Parrish.
I know the prayer is international and that many people, after coming back to Taizé, start to pray the same way in small groups within the local church.

I really would like, in any of the days I'm there, to get in contact with local communities and to join the prayer.

Does any of you know if there are any regular Taizé prayers in Prague and if it would be possible to join them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Detailed information on Taize prayers is available on the [official website](http://www.taize.fr/cs_article3201.html). Here's the full list of regular meetings in Prague:

- **First Monday** of each month at **18:30** at "Kostel svatého Martina ve zdi". Address: *Martinská 416/10, Praha 1*
- **First Wednesday** of each month at **20:00** at "Kostel sv. Františka z Assisi". Address: *U Habrovky 2, Praha 4*
- **First Thursday** of each month at **19:30** at "Augustinsky klášter u sv. Tomáše na Malé Straně". Address: *Josefská 8, Praha 1*
- **First Sunday** of each month at **19:00** at "Kostel svatého Petra a Pavla". Address: *Štulcova, Praha 2*
- **Third Friday** of each month at **18:30** at "Kostel Neposkvrněného početí Panny Marie". Address: *Ke Strašnické 1000, Praha-Strašnice*
- **Third Friday** of each month at **20:00** at "Kostel sv. Vojtěcha". Address: *Kolejní 676/4, Praha 6*
- **Fourth Thursday** of each month at **20:00** at "Kostel Panny Marie Královny míru na Lhotce". Address: *Ve Lhotce 36, Praha 4*
- **Last Thursday** of each month at **18:30** at "Evangelicky Sbor". Address: *U Pošty 6, Praha 8*
- **Last Sunday** of each month at **20:00** at "Kostel sv. Ludmily". Address: *Náměstí Míru, Praha 2*

There are also irregular meeting organized in a Facebook group called [Taize Czech Republic](https://www.facebook.com/groups/TaizevCeskerepublice/events/).